# recover accidently deleted partition

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery

I was using ubuntu 13.10 alongside w-7. there was some broken packages on ubuntu so I decided to freshly install ubuntu. while installation I selected "erase ubuntu 13.10 and reinstall" . ubuntu reinstalled but my windows and whole partition got deleted annd entire disk is assigned to ubuntu only.
there was some IMP data in that partition partition and I want to recover that data . so guys , can I recover that data and how  . please  help its urgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem , and its easy to recover whole partition within a few steps!

first , install testdisk:

`sudo apt-get install testdisk`

then get into testdisk , and I assume you wont find nothing from Quick Search so use Deeper Search,
There it will list some NTFS partitions , identify yours , highlight it and press 'p'
then when you found the desired file , press 'c' , it will ask you where to save your recovered file , locate to destination and press 'c' again!

Repeat for other files as well!

Comment: thankx bro ... for quick response ..I have recovered my all data (600 GB size).....now i can sleep silently that I have my all data.....thankx once again

Comment: Glad I could help :) Enjoy your recovered files ^