# How to recover partition that is lost while installing ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning, data-loss

I am very new to Ubuntu, and in the anxiety to install Ubuntu ended up doing a big mistake.

While installation, I chose to overwrite my current windows 7 OS; and thought that it would only format my C:
However, after installation, I have found that all my partitions are deleted and data lost.

Is there a way to recover those data? I have searched across the forums, and found out about testdisk. However, I need a very detailed step by step guide, as I completely new to Ubuntu. Some of the steps in various tutorials I found seem too advanced to me.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/370286/recover-accidently-deleted-partition)

Answer (score 0):

If you selected "use full disk" during install, then, sadly, there is no way to retrieve that data. It will be completely lost. I hope you made backups. Good luck!